# Passing columns position as input to AWK command

Tags: shell, awk

A script will transform csv file header positions
A,**C,B**,D to A,**B,C**,D and output is variable VAR_INP will be used in awk to print and create new csv file.

```
VAR_INP="TMP1=$1 ; TMP2=$2 ; TMP3=$3 ; TMP4=$4 ; $1=TMP1 ;$3=TMP2 ;$2=TMP3 ;$4=TMP4 ;"
```

I need to use this VAR_INP as input command inside awk.

```
echo "A,C,B,D" > input.csv

awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS","}
{
$VAR_INP 
print
}' input.csv
```

expected output

```
A,B,C,D
```

I am not getting desired results. its printing the input as it is.

it works only if i expand the VAR_INP and run manually

Please advise.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts, please do add samples of input and expected output in your question for better understanding thank you.

Comment: Your shell will not expand `$VAR_INP` if it is inside single quotes.

Comment: Do you really need `VAR_INP`? It feels wrong to directly inject code in the `awk` program.

Comment: Number of Columns 50+ hence, a shell doing validation of csv where position changes dynamically and need to create with a fixed order with standard header reference. hence a shell script doing validation and placing the output in a variable which is to be passed to awk for creating a file

Comment: I would use a tool like Miller for that; you just give it the order that you want in the output: `mlr --csv reorder -f 'A,B,C,D' file.csv`

Comment: Don't create awk code in shell, save it in a shell variable, and then let that shell variable expand to become part of an awk script - that's creating tight coupling between the 2 (awk and shell) and can lead to cryptic errors.

Comment: I think you're going off the rails before this with "a shell doing validation of csv where position changes dynamically and need to create with a fixed order with standard header reference" - that does not sound like something you should be doing in shell. Ask a new question with more detail if you'd like help with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it by letting the variable become part of the awk script, e.g.:

```
VAR_INP='TMP1=$1 ; TMP2=$2 ; TMP3=$3 ; TMP4=$4 ; $1=TMP1 ;$3=TMP2 ;$2=TMP3 ;$4=TMP4 ;'
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{'"$VAR_INP"'}1' input.csv
```

Output when `input.csv` contains `A,C,B,D`:

```
A,B,C,D
```

Answer (score 5):

In the following the output of commands is prefixed with `-|` . There are several issues:

1. The shell does not expand parameters between single quotes but it expands them between double quotes. So, to assign shell variable `VAR_INP` you should use single quotes, not double quotes. Else the `$...` are expanded by the shell and your variable does not contain what you want any more. Demo:

   ```
   VAR_INP="TMP1=$1 ; $1=TMP1"
   echo "$VAR_INP"
   -| TMP1= ; =TMP1
   VAR_INP='TMP1=$1 ; $1=TMP1'
   echo "$VAR_INP"
   -| TMP1=$1 ; $1=TMP1
   ```
2. To embed your shell variable in your `awk` script you cannot single-quote the script because single quotes prevent expansion. You could double quote your `awk` script, such that `$VAR_INP` is expanded by the shell before `awk` runs, but this would be very annoying because you would have to escape all other `$`... Use the `-v` option of `awk` to assign an `awk` variable, instead, and in your `awk` script refer to its value with just its name (no `$`):

   ```
   VAR_INP='TMP1=$1 ; $2=TMP1'
   awk -v VAR_INP="$VAR_INP" '
     BEGIN {print VAR_INP}
     {VAR_INP; print}' <<< "a should-become-a"
   -| TMP1=$1 ; $2=TMP1
   -| a should-become-a
   ```
3. As you can see with the previous example, you cannot embed `awk` code in variables like this, `awk` has no equivalent of the `bash` `eval`, you cannot ask `awk` to execute the string in `VAR_INP` variable as if it was `awk` code. The closest is probably the `system` function but calling `awk` from `awk` would be uselessly complicated to solve your problem.

Instead you can pass a variable with a list of numbers representing the ordered list of input field numbers in the output.

The following example should work with any POSIX `awk`, it has been tested with GNU `awk` and the `awk` that comes with macOS:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, -v order='1,3,2,4' '
  BEGIN {n=split(order,a)}
  {for(i=1;i<=n;i++) printf("%s%s", $(a[i]), i<n?OFS:ORS)}
' <<< "A,C,B,D"
-| A,B,C,D
```

Declare input and output field separators as `,`. Pass the output order as variable `order`. In `BEGIN` split `order` on the input field separator, store the result in array `a` and the number of elements in `n`. Then for each record, loop from `i=1` to `i=n` and print field number `a[i]`, followed by the output field separator (`OFS`) if `i<n`, else by the output record separator (`ORS`).

If you have many columns but want to change only few of them it is probably easier to only list the changes. In the following `from` is a list of fields to change and `to` is the corresponding list of field numbers. Here output fields 2, 3, 12 and 17 are replaced with input fields 17, 2, 3 and 12, respectively. The other 46 fields are left unmodified.

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, -v from='2,3,12,17' -v to="17,2,3,12" '
  BEGIN {split(from,a); split(to,b); for(i in a) c[a[i]]=b[i]}
  {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf("%s%s", (i in c)?$(c[i]):$i, i<NF?OFS:ORS)}
' < <(printf '%s' {1..49}, $'50\n')
-| 1,17,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,3,13,14,15,16,12,18,19,20,...,50
```

Alternatively, if you prefer, write each pair of transformations in one variable:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, -v xform='2,17 3,2 12,3 17,12' '
  BEGIN {n=split(xform,a,/[, ]/); for(i=1;i<=n;i+=2) c[a[i]]=a[i+1]}
  {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf("%s%s", (i in c)?$(c[i]):$i, i<NF?OFS:ORS)}
' < <(printf '%s' {1..49}, $'50\n')
-| 1,17,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,3,13,14,15,16,12,18,19,20,...,50
```

Answer (score 0):

skip all the loops and just use dynamically generated hard-coded fields :

```
__=' +. abc-d+ef1 3 2 4=:_'; # output field order, i.e. $1, $3, $2, $4 
                             # the extra junk is to showcase your
                             # choice of delimiter doesn't matter
```

---

```
echo 'A,C,B,D' | gawk -p- -f <( echo "$__" | 

mawk 'NF && sub("^" FS, "BEGIN { FS = OFS = \",\" } { print $",
                $!NF--)' FS='[^0-9]*' OFS=', $' ORS=' }'      )
```

---

```
A,B,C,D

# gawk profile, created Sat Aug 19 03:17:40 2023

# BEGIN rule(s)

BEGIN {
 1      FS = OFS = ","
}

# Rule(s)

 1  {
 1      print $1, $3, $2, $4
}
```

And you can do it with any amount of fields you like, including gigantic ones :

```
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," } { print \
                                  \
$128188782,  $85722244,   $123534282,
$37670758,   $60028290,   $131921030,  $101600037,  $53589940,   $48298302,
$153042678,  $100120464,  $107851922,  $11180872,   $65049972,   $153695364,
$138511919,  $15813948,   $24186787,   $83253374,   $25331659,   $59136350,
$19155798,   $85377535,   $11588418,   $28771828,   $152162471,  $31367900,
$157916915,  $105161093,  $106673752,  $61974950,   $123484701,  $149790557,
$7895384,    $87583052,   $138512906,  $89536263,   $115174743,  $106171832,
$81369675,   $20925017,   $69480437,   $111922213,  $73729383,   $138292988,
$103837216,  $118998152,  $143126137,  $147159039,  $112103403,  $28084640,
 \
$140289494,  $81098056,   $94239552,   $48406403,   $95537055,   $151629955,
$79774382,   $96998304,   $37622857,   $6383655,    $75182254,   $65407607,
$126343621,  $133931881,  $44400227,   $115040821,  $133023592,  $7542040,
$109635804,  $33383263,   $152010293,  $105053789,  $152921533,  $62330336,
$81886602,   $43712923,   $35282544,   $124629910,  $118978754,  $134056479,
$76601479,   $149677984,  $134249451,  $35652544,   $85671151,   $7297972,
$65195787,   $136249090,  $160250689,  $99290903,   $93957377,   $89791229,
$59674074,   $98419844,   $22061410    }
```

> ```
> single quotes are safely omitted since generated code fed via -f <( ) construct
> ```